# Python script for writing images not working

Tags: python-3.x, csv, opencv

I created a script which will take file names from a csv file and extract image with corresponding file name to an another
I found out that in my pc if i use imwrite with single backslash for directories it wont work but when I load the directories it is getting converted to single slash and hence img becomes null type I have included a screenshot as well

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import cv2
file=pd.read_csv("csv4.csv")
list=[]
list=file
path=os.getcwd()
img_path=path+"\\kaggle_35000"

kaggle_folders=os.listdir(img_path)
length_cv=len(file)



for x in kaggle_folders:
    img_in_each_fldr=os.listdir(img_path+"\\"+x)
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>The primary folder Now is:"+str(x)+"<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
    y=img_in_each_fldr
    length_file=len(y)
    for z in y:
        print("The image from folder:"+str(x)+"is being checked the file is"+str(z))
        for q in range(0,length_cv-1):
            #print()
            x1=str(file['16_left'][q])
            x1=x1+ ".jpeg"
            if z == x1:
                write_path=img_path+"\\"+x+str(x1)
                img=cv2.imread(write_path,1)
                destination="D:\\image_extract_python\\result\\kaggle_stage0\\"+str(z)
                cv2.imwrite(destination,img)
                print('file written'+str(z))
```

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Either use `os.path.join()` to join path components, or just use a forward slash `"/"` (which works on most systems even those which traditionally use backslash).

Comment: thankyou it works.Is this a bug in windows os?

Comment: When you write a program and it does not work, the first question should be "where is the bug in my code" not "is this a bug in the OS?"